# Минимальное количество IP-адресов необходимое web-серверу

Tags: http, веб-сервер, https

Какое минимальное количество IP-адресов необходимо web-серверу для обслуживания трех различных сайтов по HTTP и HTTPS? Почему?

Comment: Да хоть на одном `IP` адресе можно хостить 3 различных сайта

Comment: Одного вполне достаточно.

Answer (score 1):

Благодаря таким замечательным вещам, как виртуальные хосты, достаточно одного.

Например, один IP-адрес и три сайта. Как нам помогают виртуальные хосты? Система виртуальных хостов позволяет одновременно запускать несколько сайтов с одного IP-адреса. В вашем примере их (виртуальных хостов) должно быть три (по каждому на сайт). Как же происходит распределение? Распределение происходит по доменному имени, которое передаётся в заголовке `Host` при обращении к сайту. Сервер сопоставляет заголовок `Host` с доменами, прописанными в разных виртуальных хостах, и открывает нужный сайт.